# Password recovery script doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql

I have found tutorial for password recovery and trying to implement it into my current page. When user click to change his password he should enter his email and got link into his box. So far is good. The problem is when user set his new password. It doesn't saved into database.

This is reset.php

```
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    //basic validation
    if(strlen($_POST['password']) < 3)
    {
        $error[] = 'Password is too short.';
    }
    if(strlen($_POST['passwordConfirm']) < 3)
    {
        $error[] = 'Confirm password is too short.';
    }
    if($_POST['password'] != $_POST['passwordConfirm'])
    {
        $error[] = 'Passwords do not match.';
    }
    //if no errors have been created carry on
    if(!isset($error))
    {
        try 
        {
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE users SET password = :password, resetComplete = 'Yes' WHERE resetToken = :token");
            $stmt->execute(array(
            ':password' => sha1($password),
            ':token' => $row['resetToken']
            ));
            //redirect to index page
            header('Location: index.php?action=resetAccount');
            exit;
            //else catch the exception and show the error.
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) 
        {
            $error[] = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

the form

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="" autocomplete="off">
<h2>Change Password</h2>
<hr>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control input-lg"   placeholder="Password" tabindex="1">
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
<div class="form-group">
<input type="password" name="passwordConfirm" id="passwordConfirm" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Confirm Password" tabindex="1">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Change Password" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg" tabindex="3"></div>
</div>
</form>
```

Is updated only the `resetComplete = 'Yes'` the password doesn't change. So I suspect that can be something in the part for password.

Comment: `':password' => sha1($password),` - are you setting `$password` anywhere? I don't see you use that, only `$_POST['password']`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `sha1($password)` you try to access the new password as a simple variable. Previously you access it as a post variable. `$_POST['password']`

You should add this before the sha line somewhere:

```
$password = $_POST['password']
```

or access it using this way:

```
sha1($_POST['password'])
```

Comment: Yes, this was the problem. I just.. I don't know why I forget to put what is posted from the form. Thank's